# Android and SVG animation

Tags: animation, svg

I would like to run SVG animation on Android.

My SVG was created in Adobe Illustrator and it contains 4 layers. When I export all layers to SVG I get 4 groups of data which includes:

```
<g id="Layer_1">
        <g>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <g>
                            <path d...
                            <polygon p...
                    <path d......... more data.....


"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
     </g>
    <g id="Layer_1_copy"> //Second Layer
        <g>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <g>
                            <path .....
```

And so on until it covers all 4 layers.

I would like to animate it layer by layer with Drawable Animation or any other solution.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to add code that you have already tried and the errors you are getting.

Comment: I haven't tried yet because I don't know where to start from

Comment: Try looking up some tutorials, there are normally lots out there https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation